# How to DROP columns from ffdf object ? (R)

Tags: r, ff, ffbase

Could I easily drop column of `ffdf` object ?

```
library(ff);library(ffbase)    
irisdf=as.ffdf(iris)
```

How to contain only `Sepal.length` and `Species` columns ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(ff)  
irisdf <- as.ffdf(iris)
filename(irisdf)
## Referencing the same data on disk (just making an new virtual ffdf)
example1 <- irisdf[setdiff(colnames(irisdf), c("Sepal.Length", "Species"))]
filename(example1)
## Referencing new data (copying)
example2 <- clone(irisdf[setdiff(colnames(irisdf), c("Sepal.Length", "Species"))])
filename(example2)
```

Comment: I choose this answer, because its deeper

Answer (score 3):

You could try `subset` from `ffbase`

```
library(ffbase)
Subiris <- subset(irisdf, select=c('Sepal.Length', 'Species'))
dim(Subiris)
#[1] 150   2
colnames(Subiris)
#[1] "Sepal.Length" "Species"
```

Comment: does it works in place or needs double amount of memory thet on irisdf object ?